# What is the right syntax for declaring members that are struct or union?

Tags: c, struct, syntax, unions

Long story short, I generate headers out of a Sony PlayStation .SYM symbol file.

While I test the validity of the syntax with Visual Studio Code, I get the following:

> tag kind of union is incompatible with declaration of class "PacketData"

Example:

```
struct PacketData
{
    short Data[2];
    unsigned long Control;
};

struct Packet
{
    unsigned char CheckSum;
    char Action;
    short Padw;
    union PacketData Data; // tag kind of union is incompatible with declaration of class "PacketData"
};
```

That problem appears to be solvable by removing `union` before `PacketData`.

This is the struct as outputted by `DUMPSYM.EXE` command-line utility:

The struct:

```
02cc47: $00000000 94 Def class STRTAG type STRUCT size 8 name Packet
02cc5b: $00000000 94 Def class MOS type UCHAR size 0 name CheckSum
02cc71: $00000001 94 Def class MOS type CHAR size 0 name Action
02cc85: $00000002 94 Def class MOS type SHORT size 0 name Padw
02cc97: $00000004 96 Def2 class MOS type UNION size 4 dims 0 tag PacketData name Data
02ccb6: $00000008 96 Def2 class EOS type NULL size 8 dims 0 tag Packet name .eos
```

The union:

```
02cbe2: $00000000 94 Def class UNTAG type UNION size 4 name PacketData
02cbfa: $00000000 96 Def2 class MOU type ARY SHORT size 4 dims 1 2 tag  name Data
02cc13: $00000000 94 Def class MOU type ULONG size 0 name Control
02cc28: $00000004 96 Def2 class EOS type NULL size 4 dims 0 tag PacketData name .eos
```

However, why do members that are structs can **optionally** have the `struct` prefix?

```
struct Sprite
{
    unsigned char X;
    unsigned char Y;
    unsigned short Page;
    unsigned char SWidth;
    unsigned char SHeight;
    unsigned short Clut;
};

struct SpriteData
{
    struct Sprite *Sprites;
    struct Sprite *EndSprites;
    unsigned long Data;
};
```

Can you clarify on how one shall declare such members?

Comment: `union PacketData Data;`? But `PacketData` is a **`struct`**, not a `union`.

Comment: And if works by removing the `union` keyword, so you only have `PacketData Data;`, then you're programming in C++ and not C. That the error message mentions `class` is also an indicator for this.

Comment: What do you mean? That a C struct can't reference another struct unless it's a pointer? i.e. it's fundamentally wrong? I've put symbol data for information.

Comment: You seem to be very confused, here. The Dude has already indicated that you seem to be using C++ (not C) and that, once declared as a `struct`, a type cannot be redeclared as a `union`.

Comment: @aybe, In C you may not omit the `struct` keyword in the declaration of an object of structure type (though you can hide it in a typedef).  On the other hand, C++ automatically provides for struct and union tags to be usable as type aliases without the `struct` or `union` keyword.

Comment: Note also that C and C++ are *different* languages.  Although they have a shared subset large enough to program in, sticking to that subset is uncomfortable, and the result is generally non-idiomatic C++ and somewhat strained C.

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes, confused, but it's getting clearer!

Comment: @JohnBollinger Understood, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined `struct PacketData`, and later tried to create a variable/member of type `union PacketData`.  These are two different types.

The specific error message you're getting suggests that you're compiling with a C++ compiler.  In C++, you can create an instance of a `struct` or `union` without using the corresponding keyword.  This also means that in C++, you can't create a `struct` and a `union` with the same name, which is what the error message is telling you.

Given that the dump you've posted is telling you that `PacketData` is a `union`, you should define it as that type:

```
union PacketData
{
    short Data[2];
    unsigned long Control;
};
```

And if your code is in fact C, you should be compiling with a C compiler.  If this happens to be MSVC, that means your source file needs to have a .c extension.

Comment: Thank you, I figured out my error thanks to your answer: I copied/pasted the generator method without changing `struct` to `union`. Now it produces valid C and Visual Studio Code shows no more errors. 

Comment: If you do ever run into issues where C code is being compiled as C++ you can set an entire project or individual files to compile  as C to force it, but having the right extension is a pretty good idea. The option, as of Vs 2022, is under Properties->C/C++->Advanced->Compile As.

Comment: I've seen that one, it might be handy at some point. Although majority of PS1 games were written in C some appear to have been in C++; figuring that out of symbols is going to be an interesting challenge :)

Comment: All of ours were C++ish. The intersection of what different compilers supported across PS1, GameCube, XBox, and Windows was rather entertaining to navigate at times. :)